# preserving properties when using jQuery grep

Tags: jquery, arrays, grep

I'm taking an object array and extracting only the unique objects from it WHILE manipulating it. I started with inArray, but I'm testing a nested property, so it doesn't work so well. grep will test nested properties but it doesn't allow me to alter the objects before ending up with the final array.

Let me demonstrate:

This is (similar to) my starting object array:
It's got properties (eg: foo, legs.type) that I don't use in my algorithm, but their presence complicates the object structure and thus the solution.

```
 var critters = [
    {'legs':{'num':4,'type':'paw'},     'species':'cat',    'foo':11 },
    {'legs':{'num':4,'type':'paw'},     'species':'dog',    'foo':11 },
    {'legs':{'num':2,'type':'foot'},    'species':'human',  'foo':23 },
    {'legs':null,                       'species':'fish',   'foo':3 }
];
```

This is the object array I want at the end:

```
// walkingCritterTypes = [
//   { 'legs':{'num':4,'type':'paw'},     'species':['cat','dog'],    'foo':11 },
//   { 'legs':{'num':2,'type':'foot'},    'species':['human'],        'foo':23 }
// ];
```

Here's my approach using inArray. 
The + is that is allows me to grasp the items and manipualgte it before passing it tot he final array.
The - is that is doesn't work because it needs to test a nest property.

```
var walkingCritterTypesA = [];
angular.forEach(critters,function(critter,i){
    if (angular.isObject(critter.legs)) {// ditch critters with null legs
        var exists = $.inArray(critter.legs.num, walkingCritterTypes.legs.num);
        //this does not work
        // I want it to find if walkingCritterTypes.legs.num already exists
        if (exists){
            // but if it did magically work, it would allow me to 
            // operate on the walkingCritterTypes array item, 
            // adding this critter's properties (eg species) to the final array
            walkingCritterType[i].species.push(critter.species);
        }
        else{
            // this is a new type, so I'll add it
            walkingCritterType = {};
            walkingCritterType.legs = critter.legs;
            walkingCritterType.species = critter.species;
            walkingCritterType.foo = critter.foo;
            walkingCritterTypesA.push(walkingCritterType);
        }
    }
});
console.log(walkingCritterTypesA);
```

Here's my approach using grep.
The + is that it can search a nested property.
The -'s are that 1] I'm not sure howe to write the test, and 2] it's magic - it simply hands me a new array at the end, without giving me a chance to manipulate it

```
angular.forEach(critters,function(critter,i){
    if (angular.isObject(critter.legs)) {// I don't care about critters with null legs
        walkingCritterTypesG2 = $.grep(walkingCritterTypesG, function(el,i){
            return // er what? compare it to itself??
        })
    }
});


console.log(walkingCritterTypesG);
```

Not sure how to reconcile these two.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a solution, but it's inelegant. I duplicate the property needed to test-for-duplicates into its own array. Now I can use inArray on it.

```
$scope.walkingCritterTypes = [];
$scope.walkingCritterTypeIDs = []; // <----- ID in its own shallow array
angular.forEach($scope.critters,function(critter,i){
    if (angular.isObject(critter.legs)) {// drop critters with null legs
        // walkingCritterTypes.legs.num already exists in final array?
        var existingType = $.inArray(critter.legs.num, $scope.walkingCritterTypeIDs); // <----- test against ID
        if (existingType >= 0){
            // add this critter's properties (eg species) to the final array
            $scope.walkingCritterTypes[existingType].species.push(critter.species);
        }
        else{
            // this is a new type, so I'll add it to the final array
            var walkingCritterType = {};
            walkingCritterType.legs = critter.legs;
            walkingCritterType.species = new Array(critter.species);
            walkingCritterType.foo = critter.foo;
            $scope.walkingCritterTypes.push(walkingCritterType);
            $scope.walkingCritterTypeIDs.push(critter.legs.num); //  <----- add to ID array
        }
    }
});
console.log($scope.walkingCritterTypes);
```

See how I'm doing some manipulation of the valid item before depositing it in the array? That why I'm can't use grep.